# When to use hyphen before “themed”

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I understand cases where the concept modifying “themed” is a noun:
“A Star Wars–themed party”

But when the theme is an adjective, which of the following would be correct?
“A spooky-themed party”
“A spookily themed party”
“A spookily-themed party”

Here I am trying to say that the theme of the party is “spooky,” meaning there will be spooky things at the party.

Comment: Adjectives that end in *-ly* do not use hyphenation. (Because it's impossible to misunderstand that it's being used to modify the word that immediately follows.) You normally don't need a hyphen after an adjective ending in just *-y* either (for the same reason).